# How does google/Facebook synchronize data in multiple regions

Tags: distributed-computing, bigdata

I have learned that big companies like Google and Facebook synchronize my data in multiple locations around the world for high availability. How do they do that? What technologies do they use? Do they use one master or are the request to any data sent to any data centre randomly?

Comment: I would be very interested to hear more on this. I suspect at least some of this might be confidential though.

Comment: Did you happen to research more on it and find out some answers? Would be great if you can share it